# Open URL in React application via node and express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, material-ui

I am trying to open user provided URL in `reactjs` application via `node.js` and `express`.

I am using `material-ui` and `axios`. Please find below code for UI.

**Actually this a POC for a project of UX testing where URL of application to be tested given and that application will get opened in parent(main) application for testing.**

[image]

**UrlForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 16,
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200,
  },
  root: {
    ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

class UrlForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    url: ''
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  sendData = () => {
    console.log(this.state.url);
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/openurl", { url: this.state.url })
       .then(res => console.log('Data send'))
       .catch(err => console.log(err.data))
    }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={1}>
      <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
          id="outlined-name"
          label="URL"
          className={classes.textField}
          value={this.state.url}
          onChange={this.handleChange('url')}
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
        />

        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => { this.sendData(); }} size="small" className={classes.button}>
            Open
        </Button>
    </form>
    </Paper>
    );
  }
}

UrlForm.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(UrlForm);
```

Here, I am sending url to be opened on UI.

For server I am using `express-generator` and below is the code for router.
Also using `cors` and headers are set.

**app.js**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Check if the origin is whitelisted in the env vars
    res.set({
      // standard CORS headers
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Language',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',

      // addresses security issues identified by automated pen testing
      'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY',
      'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
      'X-XSS-Protection': 1,
    });
    next();
  });
```

**routes/index.js**

```
// routes/index.js

import express from 'express';
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/openurl', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(res);
})

export default router;
```

**In route /openurl I am getting the URL in req.body. How do I fetch the given url response and send it to the client to get it opened on UI ?**

**Is this a correct way or not ? As I am looking for possible options.**

Comment: What do you mean by "Open"? where do you want to open it? in the browser, or on your node server? you would like to gain access to the html on the server?

Comment: @Beaulne added screenshot for reference. And modified description.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by Open? like displaying the website the url goes to do the string of the url `http://www.theurl.com`?

Comment: @Beaulne yes displaying the website within the application and that website url will be given by user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a get call to user URL to get a response :

First, install axiosn

```
npm install axios
```

then on your node app :

```
const axios = require('axios');

router.post('/openurl', function(req, res, next) {

let url = req.body.url ; 

axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {

  //do what's you want with response

    console.log(response.data);
    res.json({  content :  response.data});

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })


})
```

Or Just a simple way  you can create an Iframe in your react app and display the URL provided by the use

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes iFrame is one of the options but I am trying to avoid it as next step is to take screenshot of given url at regular interval while user interacts with that opened url.

Comment: If you want only to take a screenshot try node-webshot is very good package: https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot

Comment: yes I saw that and will use it in next stage. in the answer you gave, I need to send response.data to the client and display it in html element, right ?